# Translucent background from opaque image

Tags: html, css, background, transparency

I have a user-uploaded image (almost always a JPEG) that I'd like to use as a background.  To make it less distracting and keep the content over it legible, I'm trying to decrease its opacity.  Essentially, I'd like something with an effect like the solid color `rgba`.

I've tried placing the background in a div with a negative bottom margin top pull the content over it:

```
<div style="height: 200px; bottom: -200px; background: url(example.jpg) no-repeat; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
<!-- page content -->
```

However, it seems hackish and only partially works.  It's exactly what I want until `opacity` is thrown in there; it puts the div on top.  (How does `opacity` affect layering!?)

I considered `position: absolute` for the background div and the content so I could play with the `z-index` but that breaks the template this is all in.

How do I get this image to be a translucent background?

Comment: With which browser are you experiencing this? Can you provide a screenshot please? It appears to be working fine for me on chrome...

Comment: I'm doing initial testing in Chrome, but ultimately it needs to support IE7+ and anything standards compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having to pull the content on top of this image, why not just add a wrapper around your content and put the image as a background of that wrapper? Then you can add a semi-transparent background to your content to make it more legible (while still being able to see the image beneath it). Try:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(example.jpg);" >
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { background: none 0 0 no-repeat; }
.content { background: url(transparency.png); }
```

Hopefully that's not too confusing!

Comment: Sure thing. Just remember that IE6 doesn't support PNG transparency by default, so if you're planning on supporting IE6, I recommend using http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/