# use rgba for background image

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Translucent background from opaque image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364461/translucent-background-from-opaque-image)

I want to use rgba but I do not have a solid background since I am using an image. Is it possible to set the image opacity to be partly faint and then including a div inside with 100% opacity without any inheritance.

```
#container2 {


position: absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
    height: 600px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
background-image:url(../images/container2_yellow_nailed.png);
 }
```

Comment: Workaround: edit the PNG and make it transparent ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364461/translucent-background-from-opaque-image?rq=1

Comment: took this workaround, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently CSS does not support controlling opacity of background image.

You can achieve similar effect by using extra element that will have same dimensions, `opacity` specified, and will be positioned under your element.

Comment: You can do it with a pseudo element also. Check this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/